# replace some tokens(strings) from a tex file with values from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, tex

I have a problem in replacing some tokens I have in TEX file with values from a dictionary in python.

I have this dictionary in python:

```
json_obj = {
   '$ORGANIZATA_SHENDETSORE$': "hejj",
   '$NJESIA_ORGANIZATIVE$': "hejj",
   '$VENDI$': "hejj",
   '$NUMRI_AMZE$': "hejj",
   '$MJEKU_NR_LICENSES$': "hejj",
   '$EMRI$': "hejj",
   '$MBIEMRI$': "hejj",
   '$GJINIA$': "hejj",
}
```

these dict keys I have as tokens in a tex file called mdr-form.tex, so I'm doing this loop as below but it show only one replaced token in the output TEX file patient-form.tex,
this is the loop:

```
with open('data/mdr-form.tex', 'r') as infile, open('data/patient-form.tex', 'w') as outfile:

        for line in infile:
            for key in json_obj:
                new_line = line.replace(key, json_obj[key])
                print line
            outfile.write(new_line)
```

Can you help me on replacing all the tokens in the input file with a better loop, or a better way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the TEX file isn't too large, you could read all of it into memory and replace one by one, and eventually write the result out to the new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `new_line` with `line` because in every iteration you lost the previous replacement as you reinitialize `new_line` with replacement of some `key` by its `value`. But if you replace `new_line` with `line` all replacements are stored in the `line` and you write this `line` to `outfile`.

```
for line in infile:
            for key in json_obj:
                line = line.replace(key, json_obj[key])
                print line
            outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the keys to match didn't have trailing `$` as well as the leading ones, you could use the built-in Python [string Template](http://python.about.com/od/pythonstandardlibrary/a/string-mod-3.htm) functionality.

Since they do, you can solve the problem with regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile("(\$.+?\$)")
>>> json_obj = {
...    '$ORGANIZATA_SHENDETSORE$': "hejj",
...    '$NJESIA_ORGANIZATIVE$': "hejj",
...    '$VENDI$': "hejj",
...    '$NUMRI_AMZE$': "hejj",
...    '$MJEKU_NR_LICENSES$': "hejj",
...    '$EMRI$': "hejj",
...    '$MBIEMRI$': "hejj",
...    '$GJINIA$': "hejj",
... }
>>> def replaceFn(matchObj):
...    # return the value matching this key, or '???' if the key isn't found.
...    return json_obj.get(matchObj.group(0), "???")
...
>>> p.sub(replaceFn, "this is $VENDI$ and $EMRI$ and an $ERROR$")
'this is hejj and hejj and an ???'
>>>
```

Note that you don't need to process your file line by line -- just read it all into a string, do the substitution all at once, and then write the resulting string back into your output file.

Comment: thank you!my dictionary keys where assigned as tokens in the TEX file, so this is a great example for me especially the error handling, but my output file is a table, where the replaced tokens, with dict values have a certain place in that table, not in string like this "this is $VENDI$ and $EMRI$ and an $ERROR$", sorry if I took you wrong!

Comment: I'm not sure I see the difference -- you're replacing text with different text (but obviously you know your requirements better than I...)